# Spring AMQP: Adding Message Processors To Auto Configured `RabbitTemplate`

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-amqp

I'm trying to call `RabbitTemplate#addBeforePublishPostProcessors` and `RabbitTemplate#addAfterReceivePostProcessors` without messing too much with Spring's autoconfiguration.

I'm trying to do this, but my `MessagePostProcessor` is not firing (I'm not seeing the 'test_header' in the message that is getting published).

```java
  @EventListener
  void test(ApplicationPreparedEvent event) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = event.getApplicationContext();
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = applicationContext.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class);
    rabbitTemplate.addBeforePublishPostProcessors(new MessagePostProcessor() {
      @Override
      public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
        message.getMessageProperties().setHeader("test_header", "test_header_value");
        return message;
      }
    });
  }
```

What is the right place to hook in for this purpose?

I've tried listening for an `ApplicationStartedEvent` as well.

Update:

Added this bean in my `@Configuration` class as per Gary's recommendation:

```java
  @Bean
  public static BeanPostProcessor rabbitTemplatePostProcessor() {
    return new BeanPostProcessor() {
      @Override
      public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if(bean instanceof RabbitTemplate) {
          RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = (RabbitTemplate) bean;

          rabbitTemplate.addBeforePublishPostProcessors(m -> {
            m.getMessageProperties()
              .setHeader(MESSAGE_PUBLISHED_TIME, currentTimeMillis());
            return m;
          });

          rabbitTemplate.addAfterReceivePostProcessors(m -> {
            m.getMessageProperties().setHeader(MESSAGE_RECEIVED_TIME, currentTimeMillis());
            return m;
          });
        }
        return bean;
      }
    };
  }
```

For anyone who's looking for an answer on how to do this if you're using `@RabbitListener` and `@SendTo`, please see Gary's edit to his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `BeanPostProcessor`.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So56155062Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So56155062Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public static BeanPostProcessor bpp() {
        return new BeanPostProcessor() {

            @Override
            public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                if (bean instanceof RabbitTemplate) {
                    ((RabbitTemplate) bean).setBeforePublishPostProcessors(m -> {
                        m.getMessageProperties().setHeader("foo", "baz");
                        return m;
                    });
                }
                return bean;
            }

        };

    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> template.convertAndSend("foo", "bar");
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    public void listen(String in, @Header("foo") String header) {
        System.out.println(in + header);
    }

}
```

**Note the `static` modifier**

**EDIT**

The template is not used for replies; the post processors go on the container factory instead.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So56155062Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So56155062Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public static BeanPostProcessor bpp() {
        return new BeanPostProcessor() {

            @Override
            public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                if (bean instanceof RabbitTemplate) {
                    ((RabbitTemplate) bean).setBeforePublishPostProcessors(m -> {
                        m.getMessageProperties().setHeader("foo", "baz");
                        m.getMessageProperties().setReplyTo("bar");
                        System.out.println("Adding header to outgoing message with payload: " + new String(m.getBody()));
                        return m;
                    });
                }
                else if (bean instanceof AbstractRabbitListenerContainerFactory) {
                    ((AbstractRabbitListenerContainerFactory<?>) bean).setAfterReceivePostProcessors(m -> {
                        m.getMessageProperties().setHeader("qux", "fiz");
                        System.out.println("Adding header to incoming message with payload: " + new String(m.getBody()));
                        return m;
                    });
                    ((AbstractRabbitListenerContainerFactory<?>) bean).setBeforeSendReplyPostProcessors(m -> {
                        m.getMessageProperties().setHeader("foo", "baz");
                        m.getMessageProperties().setReplyTo("bar");
                        System.out.println(
                                "Adding header to outgoing reply message with payload: " + new String(m.getBody()));
                        return m;
                    });
                }
                return bean;
            }

        };

    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> template.convertAndSend("foo", "bar");
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    @SendTo
    public String listen1(String in, @Header("foo") String header) {
        System.out.println(in + header);
        return in.toUpperCase();
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "bar")
    public void listen2(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

and

```
Adding header to outgoing message with payload: bar
Adding header to incoming message with payload: bar
barbaz
Adding header to outgoing reply message with payload: BAR
Adding header to incoming message with payload: BAR
BAR
```

Comment: Gary, I tried this and when it didn't work initially, I thought I must be missing something quite basic. But, after having gone through the docs not just for spring-amqp message post processing, but also for spring bean lifecycle, I still can't get this to work. The other headers I'm adding are showing up fine. It's just the headers added through both `beforePublish` and `afterReceive` post processors that don't show up. Is it relevant that I'm using `@RabbitListener` to receive and `@SendTo` to send? do those annotations use a different RabbitTemplate?

Comment: I've added my `BeanPostProcessor` code to my question.

Comment: The template is not used for replies; we publish the reply on the listener container channel. The post processors go on the container factory - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: This worked great! Thanks Gary! I generally prefer to not mess with Spring's auto configuration because it does a great job of exposing all these properties to be tweaked later: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html Just like spring takes my `Declarable` beans and uses them in the `RabbitAdmin#afterPropertiesSet`, would it be nice if it could detect my `MessagePostProcessor` beans and add them to any rabbit templates and container factories?

Comment: It's a bit tricky because we'd need some kind of indicator (marker interface or method) to tell us whether it's a before or after and/or whether it's intended for a consumer and/or producer. Also there's the issue of the order in which they might be applied. But, I suppose, not impossible. Feel free to open a github issue against spring-amqp and we'll take a look.